# why does the center point of GID_ZOOM changes?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi, win32gui

Once the Windows Zoom gestures starts why would the position of the center point change in the same gesture for subsequent GID_ZOOM messages?

I don't have a touch screen so I tried to simulate the zoom gesture. It gives me the same center point whether I obtain the center point in `GF_BEGIN` or `GF_END`.

However when I looked at windows sample over here [Microsoft-classic-samples repository, GestureEngine.cpp](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/Touch/MTGestures/cpp/GestureEngine.cpp). They are re-calculating the center by taking the average of 2 ptsLocation(s),

```
        // We read here the second point of the gesture. This is middle point between 
        // fingers in this new position.
        _ptSecond.x = gi.ptsLocation.x;
        _ptSecond.y = gi.ptsLocation.y;
        ScreenToClient(hWnd,&_ptSecond);

        // We have to calculate zoom center point 
        ptZoomCenter.x = (_ptFirst.x + _ptSecond.x)/2;
        ptZoomCenter.y = (_ptFirst.y + _ptSecond.y)/2;
```

I am confused why plsLocation would change for the same gesture i.e. before we receive the `GF_END` message?

Comment: The author of the code **decided** to update the zoom center on each input. They are free to do so. They could have decided to calculate the center once and keep it throughout the gesture. Both implementations exhibit slightly different behavior. This question is like asking, why cars are sold in different colors.

Comment: and what is that slightly different behavior ?

Comment: The center moving throughout the gesture or staying in one fixed (screen) position.

Comment: I suppose that center of the zoom is the center of the 2 fingers while zooming.and my question is exactly why that point would move ??

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you. my question still remains the same

Comment: *"center of the zoom is the center of the 2 fingers while zooming"* - The fingers move throughout the gesture. What does that mean for the center? Anyway, get yourself a touch digitizer and compare both implementations, if you cannot visualize the difference.

Comment: okay, here is how I am visualizing this: when the fingers move while zooming, they either move towards each other(zoom out) or move apart from each other(zoom in). In case of **ANY** movement other than these gesture should end (I think this is the part where things are getting complicated for me). Thank you for your support.

Comment: I challenge you to move two fingers exactly the same distance to within 0.1mm accuracy. Bonus: And exactly 180 degrees opposite direction from the starting point, also to within 0.1mm accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft-classic-samples forum "Location of the center of the zoom in GID_ZOOM Gesture"](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/issues/21) is exactly what I was looking for. I am posting the answer if someone doesn't want to go through the link.

> Human beings are not very good at moving two fingers at exactly the
>   same rate outwards. There is usually some error, which can cause the
>   center to shift slightly. (For example, when I do a pinch gesture, my
>   index finger moves faster than my thumb.)